# In C#, is there a clean way of checking for multiple levels of null references

Tags: c#, null, reference-type

For example, if I want to call the following:
`person.Head.Nose.Sniff()`
then, if I want to be safe, I have to do the following:

```
if(person != null)
    if(person.Head != null)
        if(person.Head.Nose != null)
            person.Head.Nose.Sniff();
```

Is there any easier way of formulating this expression?

Comment: Wouldn't every `Person` have a `Head` and every `Head` have a `Nose` automatically?

Comment: There are still places in the world where decapitation is practiced...

Comment: ...in which case, `Person` would become `Corpse`.

Comment: ..or just have its `IsCorpse` property turn true

Comment: To continue that rather macabre example, Person would need a Dispose method. Perhaps something like a wood chipper.

Comment: This reminds me of Objective C. You can write `[person.Head.Nose Sniff] ` right away without checking for `nil` value, though you never know if you have really Sniff it or not...

Comment: You could use the *Null Object Pattern* also ... which would require every Person to have a Head even if it's not their own.

Comment: See also http://haacked.com/archive/2009/07/14/law-of-demeter-dot-counting.aspx which discusses a proposal for a "null dereferencing operator".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Is there any easier way of formulating this expression?

With C# 6, you can use the [null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) `?`.

#### Code example

This is your original code packed into a method and assuming `Sniff()` always returns `true`:

```
    public bool PerformNullCheckVersion1(Person person)
    {
        if (person != null)
            if (person.Head != null)
                if (person.Head.Nose != null)
                    return person.Head.Nose.Sniff();
        return false;
    }
```

This is your code rewritten with the C# 6 null-conditional operator:

```
    public bool PerformNullCheckVersion2(Person person)
    {
        return person?.Head?.Nose?.Sniff() ?? false;
    }
```

The `??` is the [null-coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) and is not related to your question.

For the full example, see:
https://github.com/lernkurve/Stackoverflow-question-3701563

Answer (score 19):

First you can take advantage of short-circuiting in the boolean logic operators and do something like:

```
if (person != null && person.Head != null && person.Head.Nose != null)
{
    person.Head.Nose.Sniff();
}
```

Also note that what you are doing goes against a design guideline for developing software that is known as [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Comment: Agreed. In this case I may think about creating a method *person.Sniff()* which call *Head.Sniff()* (if not null) which call *Nose.Sniff()* (if not null). In that way, you just have to check if *person* is not null and you minimize the knowledge to friends as designed in Law of Demeter.

Comment: *"I'd prefer it to be called the Occasionally Useful Suggestion of Demeter."* Martin Fowler  http://haacked.com/archive/2009/07/14/law-of-demeter-dot-counting.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Here's another implementation along the lines of the also-mentioned Fluent Parameter Validation:  [Chained null checks and the Maybe monad](https://web.archive.org/web/20110203201906/http://devtalk.net/csharp/chained-null-checks-and-the-maybe-monad/)

Answer (score 4):

Not really, besides

```
 if (person != null && person.Head != null && person.Head.Nose != null)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [null objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) instead of null values. `Sniff` would then do nothing if any objects in the call chain are null objects.

This would not throw an exception:

```
person.Head.Nose.Sniff();
```

Your null classes could look like this (you could also use them as singletons and have interfaces for `IPerson`, `IHead` and `INose`):

```
class NullPerson : Person {
  public override Head Head { get { return new NullHead(); }
}
class NullHead : Head {
  public override Nose Nose { get { return new NullNose(); }
}
class NullNose : Nose {
  public override void Sniff() { /* no-op */ }
}
```

As a side note, in Oxygene there's an [operator](http://prismwiki.codegear.com/en/Colon_Operator) for this:

```
person:Head:Nose:Sniff;
```

Comment: I thought about posting this answer... I just couldn't think of a good reason to have a `null` body part.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: LOL! This example is really bad for this discussion! Maybe a `Default` body part then, and never allow it to be null.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Fluent Parameter Validation](http://blog.getpaint.net/2008/12/06/a-fluent-approach-to-c-parameter-validation/)

Comment: That looks interesting.  In vb.net, properties cannot be referenced without being read or written, so one could make change most of the validation methods to properties to ensure that the Check() was performed.  Not sure if there's any way to do that in C.  I don't like using methods or properties of null objects, but a static dummy instance should work just as well as "null".  Incidentally, the system does allow one to define a generic class which inherits Exception; such classes can be thrown and caught.  Further inheritance is a pain, but not impossible.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is just to use the `&&` operator instead of nested `if` statements:

```
if (person != null && person.Head != null && person.Head.Nose != null)
{
    person.Head.Nose.Sniff();
}
```

Note that you technically *could* perform a similar null check [using an expression tree](http://pastebin.com/kJ8DFVMw). Your method would have a signature like this:

```
static bool IsNotNull<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression);
```

...which would allow you to write code looking something like this:

```
if (IsNotNull(() => person.Head.Nose))
{
    person.Head.Nose.Sniff();
}
```

But this would involve reflection and would generally be much more difficult to follow in any sort of in-depth way compared to the `&&` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (person?.Head?.Nose != null) person.Head.Nose.Sniff();
```

Comment: Why not `person?.Head?.Nose?.Sniff();` ?  (I think that'll work)

Answer (score 0):

I would get rid of any use of `null` and do something like this:

```
((Nose)person.BodyParts[BodyPart.Nose]).Sniff();
```

This would require some kind of base `class` or `interface`.

```
public abstract class BodyPart
{
    public bool IsDecapitated { get; private set; }

    public BodyPart(bool isDecapitated)
    {
        IsDecapitated = isDecapitated;
    } 
}
```